# Export all images as png format from photoshop

Tags: png, export, extract, photoshop

I have a psb file, and I want to extract and export all the individual layers as png format images. Is there anyway to do that? Otherwise, I have to manually select one layer and "Save for Web&Devices". That's pretty slow.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try `File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files`?

Comment: Thanks, kolonel peteruk, I have tried your way, and yes, it can export  all the layers as png format, but it seems the images were not trimmed even I checked the Trimmed before generate these images. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Just create an Action in Photoshop and use the Automation > Batch process to apply it to all the images.